Подбор нужной комбинации через import random, import re, import string и циклом for
Нужно чтобы код создавал случайную строку и проверял по условиям в if:
import re
import random
import string
for s in range(0,1000):
    def generate_string(length):
        all_symbols = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
        result = ''.join(random.choice(all_symbols) for _ in range(length))
        return result
    def separateNumbersAlphabets(str):
        numbers = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', str)
        alphabets = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', str)
        print(*numbers,sep='')
        print(*alphabets,sep='')
        a1 = numbers
        b1 = alphabets
    #str = generate_string(6)
    #separateNumbersAlphabets(str)
        if a1 != 123 and b1 != AXA:
            print(a1,b1,sep='')
        else:
            print('Нашли! ', a,b,sep='')


Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Строку длиной с километр? А условие, которое проверяется - любит ли строка мороженое?

Я не понимаю в чем вопрос,
Почему возникают ошибки?
import re
import random
import string

def generate_string(length):
    all_symbols = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
    result = ''.join(random.choice(all_symbols) for _ in range(length))
    return result
def separateNumbersAlphabets(str):
    numbers = re.findall(r'[0-9]+', str)
    alphabets = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]+', str)
    print(*numbers,sep='')
    print(*alphabets,sep='')
    a1 = numbers
    b1 = alphabets
    if a1 != 123 and b1 != "AXA":
        print(a1,b1,sep='')
    else:
        print('Нашли! ', a,b,sep='')
        return True

flag = False
while not flag:
    flag = separateNumbersAlphabets(generate_string(100))

